# Exactly one occurrence in regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

I have a regex:

```
@"\s*[\( \[ \{]\s*[a]\s*[n]\s*[\} \] \)]\s*"
```

than detects a string within exactly one opening and closing braces: `( [ {` even if there is any number of spaces in the string anywhere.

But the problem is that it also detects `'an'` if not within braces. How do I instruct regex to detect the string 'an' only within exactly one opening and closing braces.

`abc an abc` should not match.

I want to match string like:

```
abc [ an ] abc
abc { a n } abc
abc   (   a       n     ) abc
```

And can the brackets type be matched? I mean is it possible to match only those that have closing bracket same as opening bracket?

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: can you put some working, not working example

Comment: did you want to match `an` with spaces also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the spaces in the square brackets. It's most likely matching those.

```
@"\s*[\(\[\{]\s*[a]\s*[n]\s*[\}\]\)]\s*"
```

Also, FWIW, this pattern doesn't check to ensure brackets are the same. It will get, e.g., `[an}` or `(an]`.

To do this, you'd need something like:

```
\(\s*a\s*n\s*\)|\{\s*a\s*n\s*\}|\[\s*a\s*n\s*\]
```

I'm sure there's a prettier way, but it's escaping me right now.

Comment: Is it possible to match brackets? I tried without spaces, did not work.

Comment: Try `[\(\{\[]\s*a\s*n\s*[\)\}\]]`

Comment: Try `\s*\[\s*[a]\s*[n]\s*\]\s*|\s*\(\s*[a]\s*[n]\s*\)\s*|\s*\{\s*[a]\s*[n]\s*\}\s*` to match for brackets as well. It's separated by `|` for each bracket pattern.

Comment: Ok, seems like it worked. But why `[\(\{\[]` was detecting even no occurence of a bracket? I thought it will match exactly one occurrence.

Comment: When you use the square brackets to match against any character within those brackets, a whitespace will be seen as a whitespace to match against. Your original pattern had whitespaces in it, hence those whitespaces were being matched. If you inspect the `Value` of the returned `Match`, you'll most likely see those leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^(\[ \( \{an\} \] \))$
```

This only allow the follow string:

```
[ ( {an} ] )
```

Comment: there may be zero or more spaces between `a` and `n`